# Custom Table in UIViewController Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to create table view inside of UIViewController like a below picture (I mean the second screen)

[image]

what is the best solution? "creating UIViewController then tableView and inside of tableView having custom cell"?

would you please give me some hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "creating UIViewController then tableView and inside of tableView having custom cell"? for this no need of creating the UIViewContoller u just directly create the UITableViewController having the custom cell ....

Comment: @Spynet I usually stay away from UITableViewController because using it means you cannot have any other views like a toolbar. Simply using a UIViewController with a tableView is easy to make and gives you the option of having other views in the hierarchy.

Comment: @sosborn thanks so the better way is to have UIViewController, Table view and custom cell

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want the tableview to not fill up the entire space. Yes, you can surely do `UIViewController`, let it implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, throw in a tableview and hook up the protocols, and use custom cells.

If you only want the tableview to not fill up the space horizontally (but it can still scroll all the way until it reaches your navbar), then you can just create a `UITableViewController`, and set up your cell background in the way you want. More specifically, you create 640px (or 320px) wide background images still, but only the central 600px, say, is filled in. The 20px to the right and left are transparent. (You need png to do this, of course) If you apply this background to your cells and apply another background to your `self.view`, then you can actually see your view background under the 20px on the two sides.

Note that if you choose the second approach, the cells are still full width; it's just that you are visually making them look like narrower. That's perfectly ok, but you need to customize your highlight background, too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your picture, it seems you need to create UINavigation Controller as your parent view controller and add UITabBarViewController as its rootview. then in your second tab when your click on the cell inside the table, you pushview to another view which displays your picture

Answer (score 0):

create a tab bar controller project. Every tabbar item will be a navigation controller.

Tat way u can manage both the navigation and tabs.